# Error in Kotlin but using only Java - Class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.FunctionCaller$FieldSetter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I get this error when try to run my Android application and I am not using Kotlin at all, application is written in Java...

```
Class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.FunctionCaller$FieldSetter can not access a member of class com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ManifestProcessorTask with modifiers "private"
```

Comment: I found this question, because it was used as a test for First Posts review queue (as an example of a good question). Seriously, I don't really think this question is useful, because it refers to the broken build environment on the OP's device and the chosen solution is to "turn it off and on again".

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I solved it this way:

1. Delete all the .gradle folders
2. Invalidate caches / restart
   everything is OK for me.

Comment: And all stuff you said can be done by simply doing a project rebuild (Build -> Rebuild project)

Comment: to me it worked only with the physical deletion of the folders. Rebuild I tried but nothing.

Comment: (Build -> Rebuild project) not worked for me, but deletion of folder worked. But I am still wondering, why this issue raised.

Comment: The fix works for me, but the error keeps on coming back after a while. Did anyone find a more permanent solution yet?

Comment: I have to do this every 5 minutes, this is seriously retarded Google

Comment: `./gradlew clean` also did the job for me

Answer (score 12):

```
Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Kotlin Updates -> Update channel -> Early Access Preview/Stable -> Update -> Restart
```

Or:

```
Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin Plugin Update -> Update channel -> Early Access Preview/Stable -> Update -> Restart
```

Comment: I didn't want to delete any folders or invalidate caches, but switching from Stable to EAP update channel and restarting Android Studio was enough to get my project syncing and building again. Thanks, +1.

Comment: However, invalidating caches was still needed to get rid of numerous red wriggling lines Android Studio started showing after restarting.

Answer (score 4):

1. [Install](https://gradle.org/install/) the latest Gradle version (1.10.2 at the moment of writing).
2. Install the latest version of Kotlin plugin: go to Settings <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > Languages & Frameworks > Kotlin Updates > select Update channel > click [Check again]
   My current Kotlin plugin version is 1.3.0-rc-57.

   [image: Settings]
3. Execute Build > Clean Project to remove temporary gradle files.

   [image: Build menu]
4. File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...

   [image: File menu]
5. After restarting Sync Project with Gradle files and Make Project (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>).

   [image: Sync Project with Gradle files button]

Answer (score 4):

Will be fixed in Android Studio 3.3 Canary 14: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115798277

In the mean time, use Invalidate Caches/Restart