# Gradle sync failed: tried to access method kotlin.collections.ArraysKt___ArraysKt.copyOfRange

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

Installed the latest version of Android Studio(v3.3.2) and when trying to build the project and the following error occurs.

Gradle tools version: 3.3.2

Gradle sync failed: tried to access method kotlin.collections.ArraysKt___ArraysKt.copyOfRange([Ljava/lang/Object;II)[Ljava/lang/Object; from class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Instance

Tried all the possible ways already. Please help me in fixing this.

[Error: Class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.FunctionCaller$FieldSetter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52482052/error-class-kotlin-reflect-jvm-internal-functioncallerfieldsetter/52578409)

[Error in Kotlin but using only Java - Class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.FunctionCaller$FieldSetter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311374/error-in-kotlin-but-using-only-java-class-kotlin-reflect-jvm-internal-function)

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-plugin

Comment: Run bash gradlew assembleRelease --debug from the terminal or without "w" if on windows. That should tell you what line of code or place the error is being found. Simply showing the error is not enough to help you unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have kotlin-refect as a dependency? Do you have any `copyOfRange` in your code? Any new code arround Kotlin's Arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue with Android studio 3.3.2 where it didn't allow me to build with Kotlin.

Downgrading the Android studio or using the Android Studio Canary solved my issue.

I don't think its a right solution. Suggest me with a right approach.

Comment: Looks like this is a temporary fix. But this helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem and solved by follow link:

https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/gradle-dependency-management-plugin-illegalaccesserror-tried-to-access-method-kotlin-collections-arrayskt-arraysjvmkt-copyofrange/10325/4

I figured it out. It was the dependency management plugin:

```
    dependencyManagement {
    imports {
    mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:$springBootVersion")
    }
    dependencies {
        //...
    }
```

In this POM, there is a kotlin.version property that needs to be overridden like this:

```
ext['kotlin.version'] = kotlinVersion
```

Where kotlinVersion is defined in my buildscript block at the top of the file.